# FB Graph API Counters

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like to know how to get the following statistics for the past week from Graph API:

- Page Likes (Week)
- Page Views (Week)
- Post Engagements (Week)
- **Comments (Week)**
- **Shares (Week)**

I already have Likes, Views, Engagements Working as such:

- /me/insights/page_fan_adds_unique/week
- /me/insights/page_views_total/week
- /me/insights/page_post_engagements/week

You can replace /me with your page id.

How do i get **comments count** of the page & how many times the page was **shared**?

Using: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

API Graph Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights/

Comment: If it is not listed as an available metric - then you simply _don’t_ …

Comment: It is listed, i'm just not sure in which section as there are a ridiculous amount of metric options.

Comment: _“It is listed”_ - and you know that because …? Then you have a partial name or a keyword, I assume, so that [crtl]+[f] on the documentation page should be able to help you out …